# What is an elegant way to return a float array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I basically only need to return a new float array as shown in the following code:

```
private float[] setValues(String str){
    float[] array;
    switch(str){
    case "stuff":
        float[] tmp2 = {insert stuff here};
        array = tmp2;
        break;
    case "stuff2":
         float[] tmp = {insert stuff here};  
         array = tmp;
         break;
    default:
        array = null;
    }
    return array;
}
```

I know it looks disgusting but I can't seem to find a better way to return an array (besides returning the array made in each switch instead of assigning it to the local array and returning that || There are around ~7 cases) so... How would you go about doing this elegantly?

Comment: This might be what you're getting at in your last paragraph, but what's the point in the `tmp` variable? Why not just `array = {...}`? Not much better, but saves you 1 line per case.

Comment: Well, you only need one temp array. But other than that, what's wrong with returning a temp array? Pretty standard thing to do since Java passes everything by value and not reference.

Comment: I'm more used to only having one return after the switch and in each switch define what will be returned, if that makes any sense.

Onto the part of array = {...}; it tells me it can only be used for initializing the array so it wouldn't let me use it like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to review working code, it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry Mr Roberson, I didn't realize there was a place like that. My bad :<

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review. If you have any questions or concerns, join us at our [CR Help Desk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34045).

Comment: Thanks @Phrancis , I will probably use it for later on since my question was fortunately answered before the thread was closed haha.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think this is answerable.  Why?  Because you don't explain what you are trying to do.   How the returned array is intended to be used.  What properties it is supposed to have.  @thst has made some assumptions, though he didn't state them properly and we don't know if they are valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am doing some assumptions:

- the str is really constant and can be wrapped into an enum
- the float array is constant and as such can also be put into the enum

Then: make an enum of it

```
public enum FloatEnum {
    STUFF({ float array of STUFF }),
    STUFF2({ float array of STUFF2 });

    private final float[] data;

     private FloatEnum(float[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public float[] getData() {
         return this.data;
    }

    public static float[] getDataFor(String str) {
         FloatEnum e = valueOf(str);
         return e.getData();
    }
}
```

Your method is then

```
private float[] setValues(String str) {
    // do str cleanups, if required (uppercase, trim etc)

     return FloatEnum.getDataFor(str);
}
```

Update: getDataFor needs to be static...

Comment: This seems like the best way to be honest. Thanks man!

Comment: feel free to accept as answer, thanks man :-)

Comment: Downvoting without giving a reason is lame.

Comment: I didn't downvote you :(
My upvote doesn't show because I don't have 15 reputation yet lol

Comment: @Vacster I dont blame you, no problem. I am always happy if I get some reasonable critic. But now I have a downvote and don't know what for, that is lame - have to live with that :-)

Comment: I think a Map would be better than an enum here... Just a personal preference though. I think it expresses the semantics better; you map one form of data to another, as opposed to a collection of constants that are related (not my downvote though; this is a valid solution).

Comment: @BenKnoble I would agree, if the data wasn't constant. My two assumptions give that the op has a constant lookup key that he wants to fetch the constant data for. After mapping to the enum value by name, you can use the data as constant item in your code. This may match the semantics better than a per se mutable map.

Comment: This is true; a mutable map might pose more problems. I remember enough java to know if it has an immutable map (though itd be easy to make the type by wrapping the actual map inside and only writing methods to retrieve data with a factory method to create it).

Comment: This leads off, but we are closed already anyway :-) Yes, there are immutable collections, you could use one of them.